# Minimum number of Meeting Rooms required to Accomodate all Meetings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have the following columns in a table called meetings: meeting_id - int, start_time - time, end_time - time. Assuming that this table has data for one calendar day only, how many minimum number of rooms do I need to accomodate all the meetings. Room size/number of people attending the meetings don't matter.

Here's the solution:

```
select * from
(select t.start_time, 
        t.end_time, 
        count(*) - 1 overlapping_meetings, 
        count(*) minimum_rooms_required,
        group_concat(distinct concat(y.start_time,' to ',t.end_time) 
separator ' // ') meeting_details from 
(select 1 meeting_id, '08:00' start_time, '09:15' end_time union all
select 2, '13:20', '15:20' union all
select 3, '10:00', '14:00' union all
select 4, '13:55', '16:25' union all
select 5, '14:00', '17:45' union all
select 6, '14:05', '17:45') t left join 

(select 1 meeting_id, '08:00' start_time, '09:15' end_time union all
select 2, '13:20', '15:20' union all
select 3, '10:00', '14:00' union all
select 4, '13:55', '16:25' union all
select 5, '14:00', '17:45' union all
select 6, '14:05', '17:45') y

on t.start_time between y.start_time and y.end_time

group by start_time, end_time) z;
```

My question - *is there anything wrong with this answer? Even if there's nothing wrong with this, can someone share a better answer?*

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry - Thanks. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meetings can "overlap".  So, `GROUP BY start_time, end_time` can't figure this out.

Not every algorithm can be done in SQL.  Or, at least, it may be grossly inefficient.

I would use a real programming language for the computation, leaving the database for what it is good at -- being a data repository.

```
Build a array of 1440 (minutes in a day) entries; initialize to 0.
Foreach meeting:
    Foreach minute in the meeting (excluding last minute):
        increment element in array.
Find the largest element in the array -- the number of rooms needed.
```

Comment: I completely agree with you that SQL/databases are not meant for this kind of stuff. I posted this out of curiosity. Doing this using a programming language is both, easy and efficient.

Comment: @MontyPython - Yeah, it could probably be done in MySQL.  And sometimes I bite on questions like yours, but usually I punt and say "Don't use SQL".  MariaDB's "sequence" tables would make it a lot easier, but still not simple.  And CTEs might help.  And maybe Windowing functions.

Answer (score 16):

Let's say you have a table called 'meeting' like this -

[image]

Then You can use this query to get the minimum number of meeting Rooms required to accommodate all Meetings.

```
select max(minimum_rooms_required)
from (select count(*) minimum_rooms_required
      from meetings t
      left join meetings y on t.start_time >= y.start_time and t.start_time < y.end_time group by t.id
) z;
```

This looks clearer and simple and works fine.

Comment: @jmoriarty can you explain your claim because I am getting correct answers using above query.

Comment: Thanks for the minimal solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Meetings](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Starttime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
[EndTime] [time](7) NOT NULL) ON [PRIMARY] )GO
```

sample data set:

```
INSERT INTO Meetings VALUES (1,'8:00','09:00')
INSERT INTO Meetings VALUES (2,'8:00','10:00')
INSERT INTO Meetings VALUES (3,'10:00','11:00')
INSERT INTO Meetings VALUES (4,'11:00','12:00')
INSERT INTO Meetings VALUES (5,'11:00','13:00')
INSERT INTO Meetings VALUES (6,'13:00','14:00')
INSERT INTO Meetings VALUES (7,'13:00','15:00')
```

To Find Minimum number of rooms required run the below query:

```
create table #TempMeeting
(
 id int,Starttime time,EndTime time,MeetingRoomNo int,Rownumber int
)
insert into #TempMeeting select id, Starttime,EndTime,0 as MeetingRoomNo,ROW_NUMBER() 
over (order by starttime asc) as Rownumber from Meetings

declare @RowCounter int
select top 1 @RowCounter=Rownumber from #TempMeeting order by Rownumber

WHILE  @RowCounter<=(Select count(*) from #TempMeeting)
BEGIN
     update #TempMeeting set MeetingRoomNo=1
     where Rownumber=(select top 1 Rownumber from #TempMeeting where 
     Rownumber>@RowCounter and Starttime>=(select top 1 EndTime from #TempMeeting 
     where Rownumber=@RowCounter)and MeetingRoomNo=0)set @RowCounter=@RowCounter+1
END

select count(*) from #TempMeeting where MeetingRoomNo=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a table `meetings` with columns `id, start_time` and `end_time`. Then the following query should give correct answer.

```
with mod_meetings as (select id, to_timestamp(start_time, 'HH24:MI')::TIME as start_time,
to_timestamp(end_time, 'HH24:MI')::TIME as end_time from meetings)
select CASE when max(a_cnt)>1 then max(a_cnt)+1 
            when max(a_cnt)=1 and max(b_cnt)=1 then 2 else 1 end as rooms 
from
(select count(*) as a_cnt, a.id, count(b.id) as b_cnt from mod_meetings a left join mod_meetings b 
on a.start_time>b.start_time and a.start_time<b.end_time group by a.id) join_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample DATA:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS meeting;
CREATE TABLE "meeting" (
"meeting_id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
"start_time"    TEXT NOT NULL,
"end_time"  TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("meeting_id")
);

INSERT INTO meeting values (1,'08:00','14:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (2,'09:00','10:30');
INSERT INTO meeting values (3,'11:00','12:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (4,'12:00','13:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (5,'10:15','11:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (6,'12:00','13:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (7,'10:00','10:30');
INSERT INTO meeting values (8,'11:00','13:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (9,'11:00','14:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (10,'12:00','14:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (11,'10:00','14:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (12,'12:00','14:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (13,'10:00','14:00');
INSERT INTO meeting values (14,'13:00','14:00');
```

Solution:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS Final;
CREATE VIEW Final AS SELECT time, group_concat(event), sum(num) num from (
select start_time time, 's' event, 1 num from meeting
union all 
select end_time time, 'e' event, -1 num from meeting)
group by 1
order by 1;

select max(room) AS Min_Rooms_Required FROM (
    select 
        a.time,
        sum(b.num) as room
    from 
        Final a
        , Final b
    where a.time >= b.time
    group by a.time
    order by a.time
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the explanation to gashu's nicely working code (or otherwise a non-code explanation of how to solve it with any language). 
Firstly, if the variable 'minimum_rooms_required' would be renamed to 'overlap' it would make the whole thing much easier to understand. Because for each of the start or end times we want to know the numbers of overlapping ongoing meetings.  When we found the maximum, this means there's no way of getting around with less than the overlapping amount, because well they overlap.

By the way, I think there might be a mistake in the code. It should check for t.start_time or t.end_time between y.start_time and y.end_time. Counterexample: meeting 1 starts at 8:00, ends at 11:00 and meeting 2 starts at 10:00, ends at 12:00.
(I'd post it as a comment to the gashu's answerbut I don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for Lead() analytic function

```
select 
sum(needs_room_ind) as min_rooms
from (
      select
      id,
      start_time,
      end_time,
      case when lead(start_time,1) over (order by start_time asc) between start_time 
      and end_time then 1 else 0 end as needs_room_ind
      from
      meetings
   ) a
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, I wanna to take the difference between how many meeting are started and ended at the same time when each meeting_id is started (assuming meeting starts and ends on time)

my code was just like this :

```
with alpha as
(
  select a.meeting_id,a.start_time,
         count(distinct b.meeting_id) ttl_meeting_start_before, 
         count(distinct c.meeting_id) ttl_meeting_end_before
  from meeting a
  left join
    (
      select meeting_id,start_time from meeting 
    ) b
  on a.start_time > b.start_time
  left join
    (
      select meeting_id,end_time from meeting 
    ) c
  on a.start_time > c.end_time
  group by a.meeting_id,a.start_time
)
select max(ttl_meeting_start_before-ttl_meeting_end_before) max_meeting_room
from alpha
```